# Could we import another namespace without require or include?

Tags: php, namespaces

I saw in Google, Facebook API(s) importing namespaces without include or require relevant php file that contained importing namespace. Like this

```
<?php

namespace Facebook;
use Facebook\Exception;

//more codes here

?>
```

Following php file doesn't refer (require or include) any php file with Facebook\Exception namespace. Is that correct and shall it execute without any errors?

Comment: This technique works by leveraging PHP's support for [autoloaders](http://php.net/autoload)

Answer (score 1):

You can use php native autoloading

http://php.net/autoload

or the composer autoloader

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading